# Twitter Bootstrap accordion full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a Bootstrap page with an accordion/collapsible on it. I'd like that accordion to take up the full height of the page (minus the navigation bar at the top).

Does anyone have pointers on how to best achieve that? If a CSS solution isn't an option, I'm willing to use JavaScript.

Here's the markup:

```
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
          Navigation
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
      <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
            Anim pariatur cliche...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
            Anim pariatur cliche...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
            Anim pariatur cliche...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ye2xq/2/

Thanks!

Comment: From what i have understood, in a page there can be any no. of accordion    lets say 4 or 5. So if you expand the first accordion the other 4 accordion below it should come within 100% of the browser height including the expanded accordion and no scrollbar should appear while expanding the accordion? Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean the entire accordion you have two potential solutions.

Firstly, if it is possible to set a fixed height of the parent you can simply use `height:100%;`
example markup would be something like:

HTML
`<div class="page">
     <div class="accordion">
          content
     </div>
</div>`

CSS

`.page { height: 800px; //or whatever }
.accordion { height: 100%; }`

Alternatively, as this is often not possible. You can use javascript/jQuery. Something like this would work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //cache the accordion object to variable
    var accordion = $('div.accordion');

    //set accordion object equal to target divs height 
    accordion.height($('div.page').height());

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ye2xq/11/

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you could do something similar to the sticky footer for the top nav bar, which assumes the height won't change

**CSS**

```
.navbar {background-color:#999;}
.accordion {background-color:yellow; top:18px; bottom:0; position:absolute;}
```

Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ye2xq/31/

Comment: Does this JSFiddle still work?  Nothing seems to happen when I click on Item #1 or Item #2 in Chrome.